# A java process launched from another java process without & doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, process, background

Suppose a little Java procces whose task is to launch other Java processes. The procedure is similar to the following:

```
String[] command = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "some.sh" + " &"};
Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
//rest
```

This first option works because the `&`, and this another one doesn't work:

```
String[] command = { "/bin/sh", "some.sh"};
Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
//rest
```

Q: What is the meaning of "it doesn't work"?
A: Both options launch the process but in the second one the child process stops working after a few seconds, however, if I inspect running processes (`ps aux | grep some.sh`), it is there (but doing nothing). The first option works fine, it lauches process and the child does its task.

I don't understand why when I launch child process without background it appears like active in `ps` processes list but it isn't doing nothing.

Comment: Didn't you forget a `-c` in your second example? Also, why on earth go through a shell at all and not use `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: Yes @fge, `-c` is necessary. So, are you telling me that the problem is not to use ProcessBuilder?

Comment: Actually it throws a sh, I edited to make it right.

Comment: Without knowing what the `some.sh` does, it is quite difficult to know what is happening. Is the run uninterrupted if you launch `some.sh` from the command line?

Comment: @fge: `some.sh` launches another .jar which has a lot of VM arguments and I prefer prepare it in a sh. And yes, if I launch `some.sh` from the command line it works fine, even if I launch it like the first option (with `&`), it works rigth too. The key is in `&`.

Comment: I've never needed to launch something from the shell in a Java program in order to launch another Java program.  Have you considered looking into [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for performing shell tasks?  It can do mostly anything you need, and for the rest, you can create custom tasks in Java.

Comment: @Neil: This process takes care of another processes that must be active, launching them if they aren't and let me know by email. It's a really small controller. Do you think ant is more appropriate? I have to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Amanda It could be worth your while if it's something which you may need to modify in the future, without having to stop your program for updates.  It has all the advantage of shell scripting while being platform independent.  Also, I think I may know the answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Launching a command in Unix with `&` at the end implies that it will be followed by another command.  I presume that if the process is halted and doing nothing, it is likely because it isn't intelligent enough to realize that another command isn't coming.

Therefore, the reason why the first doesn't close but seems to be doing nothing is precisely because of this added `&`.  I imagine that `some.sh` ends.  Perhaps it shouldn't, but it is.

[Please look into Apache Tomcat daemon](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) for information concerning how to create a daemon (under section Unix daemon).  In your code, you should create a shutdown variable and shutdown hook so that when your daemon is halted, you can execute code:

```
private volatile boolean shutdown = false;

...

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // What to run on shutdown
        shutdown = true;
    }
});
```

Once you have this, perform some action every so often in an infinite loop (using sleep of course or your CPU would be wasted):

```
while(!shutdowwn) {
    // Perform action here every 1000 milliseconds.
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Apache Tomcat daemon can be run on windows as a service or just as well in Linux/Unix.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you're right about the solution that I've to create a daemon. However, I've understood in your answer that the child process doesn't work  with `&`, it is the opposite, `&` working. Your reply has been very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Amanda Hmm, that is the opposite of what I would have expected.  In any case, glad to have been at least partially helpful.